# Manual Update in AWSTATS

Tags: logging, update, awstats, manual

I need to manually update the logs for some 7 days in the month of FEB,2011- Which has been somehow skipped by AWSTATS. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I looked at this in some detail, AwStats could not accomodate back filling of gaps in data - it maintains cumulative values for a lot stuff. You need to restore from a backup before the gap and roll forward the logs from there.